lambda not showing console logs after implementing makeHandlerIdempotent
I have a lambda function that I added the lambda powertools function makeHandlerIdempotent but now I'm not getting any logs when I run the function.

This is the intended behavior of the idempotency middleware. When you make an identical request within the expiry window, it returns the previously stored result without re-invoking the handler function. Any logs or code within the handler body won’t execute again.
